# MySQL Connection timing out C#

Tags: c#, mysql

My Code is below:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "mysql.***********.com";
conn_string.UserID = "********";
conn_string.Password = "********";
conn_string.Port = 3306;
conn_string.Database = "*********";
var connectionString = conn_string.ToString();
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

The error that I get is System.TimeoutException
Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

The code worked before when I was on a different network, but now that I have changed networks it no longer works and I get a timeout error on the connection.Open(); command.

Any ideas on what is wrong? I know that the database/server and even the computer I'm using has not changed but my network has.

Comment: Does `mysql.***********.com` run a firewall that blocks port 3306?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using MySql Workbench? You could try to increase the COnnectionTimeout property.

Comment: I tried increasing the connection timeout property. And mysql.***.com doesn't block port 3306, as I was able to connect before?

Comment: to be sure try to telnet mysql.***********.com 3306. and you didn't answer @Steve if you are able to connect using MySql workbench from the same machine hosting your code

Comment: did you install software like sql or skype? i think some of your apps using the same port which is 3306.

Comment: I did not install new software, I also could not connect via MySQL Workbench or telnet